# Disable Shopsystem

Tags: checkout, cart

first of all, I am absolutely new to Magento.
I want to put a Magento installation in catalog mode.

Is it possible to disable all add to cart buttons, the cart, and the checkout?

I bought a theme and I don't know where to start.

Read about disabling Mage_Checkout but I don't have a configuration button under "System"

Please anybody help...

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To disable add to cart you just need to return false in `isSalable` method in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` class. So, You can write an after plugin for this method. Please follow these steps below to create a small module.

> app/code/MilanDev/DisableCart/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MilanDev_DisableCart',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/MilanDev/DisableCart/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MilanDev_DisableCart" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/DisableCart/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="MilanDev_DisableCart_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Product" sortOrder="10" type="MilanDev\DisableCart\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/DisableCart/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
<?php
namespace MilanDev\DisableCart\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model;

class Product
{

    public function afterIsSalable(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,

i created all the Files and folders. How do i activate the Module? Sorry for the lack of knowledge. Do i have to do this via ssh?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: go to magento root folder using comand line and run the following command:
`php bin/magento module:enable MilanDev_DisableCart -c && php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: getting: Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will b                                                     e suppressed on further calls in /www/htdocs/w018f7f2/rossbach/vendor/colinmolle                                                     nhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81